# Sorted Stacks getting merged at main method

Tags: java

A method `sortStack()` arranges an unsorted stack in descending order.
But when I try to use the method for 2 individual stacks, the second sorted stack gets merged with the first sorted stack. Can anyone help with what I am missing?

```
    static Stack<Integer> descending = new Stack<Integer>();
    static Stack<Integer> tmpStack = new Stack<Integer>();

    public static Stack<Integer> sortStack(Stack<Integer> input){

    while(!input.isEmpty()) {
        int tmp = input.pop();
        while(!tmpStack.isEmpty() && tmpStack.peek() > tmp) {
            input.push(tmpStack.pop());
        }
        tmpStack.push(tmp);
    }

    while(!tmpStack.isEmpty()) {
        descending.push(tmpStack.pop());
    }
    return descending;
}

public static void main(String args[]){

            Stack<Integer> A = new Stack<Integer>(); 
            A.push(34); 
            A.push(3); 
            A.push(31);

            System.out.println("unsorted: " + A);
            Stack<Integer> C = sortStack(A);
            System.out.println("sorted: " + C);

            Stack<Integer> B = new Stack<Integer>();
            B.push(1); 
            B.push(12); 
            B.push(23);

            System.out.println("unsorted: " + B);
            Stack<Integer> D = sortStack(B);
            System.out.println("sorted: " + D);        
        }
```

**Output**

```
unsorted: [34, 3, 31]

sorted: [34, 31, 3]

unsorted: [1, 12, 23]

sorted: [34, 31, 3, 23, 12, 1]
```

Comment: Perhaps if you included the code of `sortStack` we could help

Comment: Post sortStack method

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted so the bug is in the sortStack method, most likely the method is using a static variable that doesn't get cleared between calls

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Stack<Integer> sortStack(Stack<Integer> stack) {
    stack.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());
    return stack;
}
```

**Output:**

```
unsorted: [34, 3, 31]
sorted: [34, 31, 3]
unsorted: [1, 12, 23]
sorted: [23, 12, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `Stack<Integer> tmpStack = new Stack<Integer>();` as local variable instead of class variable.

```
public static void main(String args[]){

            Stack<Integer> A = new Stack<Integer>(); 
            A.push(34); 
            A.push(3); 
            A.push(31);

            System.out.println("unsorted: " + A);
            Stack<Integer> C = sortStack(A);
//After this method call tmpStack will have [3, 31, 34]
            System.out.println("sorted: " + C);

            Stack<Integer> B = new Stack<Integer>();
            B.push(1); 
            B.push(12); 
            B.push(23);

            System.out.println("unsorted: " + B);
            Stack<Integer> D = sortStack(B);
//After this method call tmpStack will have [34, 31, 3, 1, 12, 23]
//Here you are appending 1, 12, 23 values to existing tmpStack[3, 31, 34]
            System.out.println("sorted: " + D);        
        }
```

Solution :

Declare `tmpStack` as a local variable.

Also If you want to sort in descending order, you don't need to add extra code

```
while(!tmpStack.isEmpty()) {
    descending.push(tmpStack.pop());
}
```

You can just change the condition to '>' or '<'

Ascending Order : `while(!tmpStack.isEmpty() && tmpStack.peek() > tmp) {}`

Desecending Order : `while(!tmpStack.isEmpty() && tmpStack.peek() < tmp) {}`

```
public static Stack<Integer> sortStack(Stack<Integer> input) {

    Stack<Integer> tmpStack = new Stack<Integer>();

    while (!input.isEmpty()) {
        int tmp = input.pop();
        while (!tmpStack.isEmpty() && tmpStack.peek() < tmp) {
            input.push(tmpStack.pop());
        }
        tmpStack.push(tmp);
    }

    //while (!tmpStack.isEmpty()) {
    //  descending.push(tmpStack.pop());
    //}
    return tmpStack;
}
```